# Is it possible to place a DIV between two paragraphs using CSS only?

Tags: html, css

I think I cannot do that one in CSS, but wanted to see whether someone would have such a solution...

I have a div with the page content, a div which can be in several different location in the HTML, and a set of paragraphs. The CSS would have to place the second div between two paragraphs.

There is a sample HTML:

```
<div id="to-be-placed">Move Me</div>
<div id="content">
  <p>P1</p>
  <p>P2</p>
  <p>P3</p>
  <p>P4</p>
  <p>P5</p>
</div>
```

Say we want to place the "#to-be-placed" div after the 3rd paragraph, is there a way to do that in CSS? I can reference the 3rd paragraph as so:

```
content.p:nth-child(3)
```

But I really don't see a way to tell CSS to move my DIV to that location...

Note: the #to-be-placed div could be inside the #content div, at the beginning or at the end.

*P.S. Please, don't come up with hard coded sizes and positions. That won't work.*

*P.S. Just in case you get all excited about jQuery. I know how to do it with jQuery. So no, I don't need you to give me such an answer. (see [How to add div tag in-between two paragraphs when wrapped inside main div using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13155749/how-to-add-div-tag-in-between-two-paragraphs-when-wrapped-inside-main-div-using#13155876) for those who wonder.)*

Comment: How would we decide where to put it?

Comment: That I know. It could be after paragraph 3 or 5. That part is hard coded.

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done using CSS, as CSS does not provide any mechanism for moving elements in HTML, only for styling existing elements and adding new content through the use of pseudoelements. The best you're going to get is a solution that uses JavaScript or jQuery.

---

If you only want to add styled text content, you can add that using the `::after` pseudo-element in CSS, but it does not support HTML, only plain text:

```css
p:nth-child(2)::after {
    content: "- Added content";
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <p>P1</p>
  <p>P2</p>
  <p>P3</p>
  <p>P4</p>
  <p>P5</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately my DIV will include HTML tags too... even though it isn't shown in my example.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that exactly, but a possible workaround would be to define the div as the ::after element on the 3rd p element. This technically puts the div inside the p, but it might do what you're looking for.

```
p:nth-child(3)::after {
    content: "Move Me";
    display: block;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/me5su05f/1/

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer: No you cannot do that.** CSS (Cascading Style Sheet) is designed for styling. It is not designed to be used to manipulate DOM elements. JavaScript on the other hand is built for doing that. So if you happen to be wanting to use CSS for manipulating your DOM then you might want to re-think your approach to the solution.

Comment: The fact is that when I look at the [CSS Zen Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/) it feels like things are being moved... I guess that they mainly use float left/right and a few other similar tricks.

Comment: Yeah. Stuff they do at zen garden are amazing. But they are all experimental.  But if CSS starts manipulation of DOM then it sort of moves away from its actual purpose of existence I guess.

Answer (score 0):

For those who stumble upon this answer (like me) who don't mind using JavaScript:

I wanted to allow users to add content between paragraphs. So for my use case I only cared about nearby paragraph tags above or below a click.

As such, I used this code:

```js
const MAX_TRIES_PER_DIR = 10;
const PX_SHIFT_EACH_TRY = 2;

function findClosestPToClick(e) {
  const above_res = checkNearbyPosForP(e.pageX, e.pageY, -PX_SHIFT_EACH_TRY, MAX_TRIES_PER_DIR);
  const above_dist = above_res ? Math.abs(e.pageY - above_res.y) : Infinity;
  const below_res = checkNearbyPosForP(e.pageX, e.pageY, PX_SHIFT_EACH_TRY, MAX_TRIES_PER_DIR);
  const below_dist = below_res ? Math.abs(e.pageY - below_res.y) : Infinity;
  
  if (above_dist <= below_dist) {
    if (above_dist === 0) {
      const el_height = above_res.el.offsetHeight;
      if (Math.sign(e.offsetY - el_height / 2) < 0) {
        return {
          el: above_res?.el,
          place_before: true,
        }
      }
      return {
        el: above_res?.el,
        place_before: false,
      }
    }
    return {
      el: above_res?.el,
      place_before: false,
    }
  } 
  return {
    el: above_res?.el,
    place_before: true,
  };
}

function checkNearbyPosForP(x, y, shift, num_tries) {
  const p = document.elementFromPoint(x, y)?.closest('p');
  if (p) return { el: p, y };
  if (num_tries > 1) {
    return checkNearbyPosForP(x, y + shift, shift, --num_tries);
  }
  return;
}

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const res = findClosestPToClick(e);
  if (res.el) {
    return console.log(res.el.innerText, res.place_before);
  }
  console.log('No p found near click');
});
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/ZachSaucier/pen/oNOGVXR??editors=0010)